# What is the real shape of this image?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

Both `cv2.imread` and `skimage.io.imread` loads image into a `ndarray`, but with different shapes.

```
import cv2
from skimage import io

im = cv2.imread(imfile)
print im.shape  # (2592, 1936, 3)

im = io.imread(imfile)
print im.shape # (1936, 2592, 3)
```

What is the real width/height of this image ? Why those shapes are different ?

**Edit:**  This problem only appears with some images.

**Solution**: It seems that OpenCV 3.1+ handles [EXIF orientation](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html), so it loads and rotate the image and `io.imread` don't.

So the real orientation of the image is the one returned by `io.imread`.

Comment: They use different layouts for the orientations. The true shape is the one you get in your file. See it by yourself and then you know how both libraries make the layout, and when you refer a single pixel, ensure you use [x, y] or [y, x] properly.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is format specific and library specific. That... unless for a same file extension and library you get different layouts for different images

Comment: Images could be described in both ways. Some identifies the width as the vertical columns from the left to the right, and some identifies the width as the longest rows. It's very subjective from those who wrote the functions on how to read the image.